# dynamic behavior of factory class

Tags: java, design-patterns, oop

I have a factory class that serves out a bunch of properties.

Now, the properties might come either from a database or from a properties file.

This is what I've come up with.

```
public class Factory {

    private static final INSTANCE = new Factory(source);

    private Factory(DbSource source) {
        // read from db, save properties
    }

    private Factory(FileSource source) {
        // read from file, save properties
    }

    // getInstance() and getProperties() here
}
```

What's a clean way of switching between these behaviors based on the environment.
I want to avoid having to recompile the class each time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Dependency Injection is the way to do it.

- **Overview:** http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection
- **Spring DI:** http://www.vogella.de/articles/SpringDependencyInjection/article.html#usageannotations
- **Guice DI:** http://code.google.com/p/google-guice/

Generally, using dependency injection in your situation would look like this (example is for Spring DI, would look little different for Guice but the idea is the same):

```
public interface Factory {
    Properties getProperties();
}

public class DBFactory implements Factory {
    Properties getProperties() {
        //DB implementation
    }
}

public class FileFactory implements Factory {
    Properties getProperties() {
        //File implementation
    }
}

public SomeClassUsingFactory {
    private Factory propertyFactory;

    public void setPropertyFactory(Factory propertyFactory) {
        this.propertyFactory = propertyFactory;
    }

    public void someMainMethod() {
        propertyFactory.getProperties();
    }
}

//Spring context config
<!-- create a bean of DBFactory (in spring 'memory') -->
  <bean id="dbPropertyFactory"
    class="my.package.DBFactory">
    <constructor-arg>
      <list>
        <value>Some constructor argument if needed</value>
      </list>
    </constructor-arg>
  </bean>
 <!-- create a bean of FileFactory (in spring 'memory') -->
  <bean id="filePropertyFactory"
    class="my.package.FileFactory">
    <constructor-arg>
      <list>
        <value>Some constructor argument if needed</value>
      </list>
    </constructor-arg>
  </bean>
<!-- create a bean of SomeClassUsingFactory -->
  <bean id="MainClass"
    class="my.package.SomeClassUsingFactory">
    <!-- specify which bean to give to this class -->
    <property name="propertyFactory" ref="dbPropertyFactory" />
  </bean>
```

Then, in different environment you just swap your xml config file with some other file that sets the property to filePropertyFactory and you get it passed into the SomeClassUsingFactory.

Comment: Or, you introduce a `Factory()` constructor which inspects the environment properties and calls the file- or database constructor respectively.

Comment: Would work if you will have only 2 ways to get properties for whole lifetime of the project. But if you need to add some TCPPropertyFactory, or XmlPropertyFactory? You would have to change that Factory() constructor each time a new PropertyFactory appears. And with proper IoC mechanism - you would only need to edit a configuration file for that.

Answer (score 1):

Simply, don't use singletons.

"Parameterise from Above." Construct the required implementation at a place in the code where it makes sense. Pass the instance down to those objects that need it as they are constructed.

Comment: I want to add that this is called Inversion of Control, Dependency Injection being a subtype of IoC. You can read more about it here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversion_of_control

Comment: @Max "IoC" is typically used in the context of [true] frameworks (where the library is the application, upcalling into the "business" code). I mean a simple, globalless style of code with a sort of strict hierarchical structure of implementation(ish) dependency. IYSWIM. I certainly would advise against ploughing in with Dependency Injection frameworks (until they make sense).

Comment: Yes, it is 'typically' used in that context. But doing it all manually does not make it *not* IoC.

Comment: @Max I think IoC implies callbacks, which is not what is happening here.

Comment: "Paraterise ..." -- should that be paraMEterise?

Answer (score 0):

You could define something like:

```
public abstract Factory  {
    // define all factory methods here
    public static Factory getFactory(FactoryType type, Object source) {
        if (type == FactoryType.DB) {
             return new DbFactory(source);
        }
        if (type == FactoryType.PROPERTIES) {
             return new PropertiesFactory(source);
        }
    }
}

public DbFactory implements AbstractFactory { .. }
public PropertiesFactory implements AbstractFactory { .. }
```

- You can use `instanceof` instead of the `enum`
- if you want your factories to be singleton, replace instantiation (`new`) with a static method